# Overwrite Css Files

Tags: css

I'm using uikit.css and I create others files for modify what I want. 
I'm confused because I charging the file in cascade but 0 effect

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/uikit.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

With !important, it's be great but I wont use it always in all my file.

[Css capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVt6g.png)

uikit.css is main or library css. Trying to override some of style in main.css

If I want to add class for style my selector. How can I do this ? Because the class is overwrited by the uikit.css ?

Comment: Which CSS are you typing into and which one are you trying to overwrite? - CSS is read from top to bottom and will take the style that is last read by the browser. So if you are writing your code above the code you want to overwrite then it wont happen, unless you are more specific on how you are targeting an element of HTML

Comment: user different selector or add class to it and override that style in main.css. Something like .uk-navbar-container .uk-navbar-nav li {}

Comment: Please include the relevant code _as text_, not images.

Comment: @Andrew for exemple I'm trying to replace font, or color of a navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the CSS files get written from top to bottom. 
In your case that means, by default everything written in main.css will override uikit.css.

`<link href="{{ asset('css/uikit.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` this is written first

`<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` this is written last

There is a big but to this.

It will only override what is exactly the same style or if you are being more specific with selectors.

Example uikit.css:

```
.uk-navbar-nav > li > a { 
  font-family: something; 
}
```

Example main.css:

```
.uk-navbar-nav > li > a { 
  font-family: something;  //this will override uikit.css
}
```

I have a simple trick up my sleeve, that I sometimes use. 
Watch my Gyazo video here: [Tutorial; how to get class with DevTools](https://gyazo.com/e86b814eacc8afc23575d8274d2f42b3)

The trick works almost every time because it will always take the currently used selectors on the specific element. But the best way is to actually not override at all.
Begin working with uikit in SCSS or SASS is my absolute best advice.

Comment: thx for your answer. I understand what you mean. I did it and it's right. But like you said, I don't want to override at all. But sometimes, I want to add class  for change only one propertie. I can't dos this cause he is overwritted : /

Comment: You can definitely just override one property. 
Just because you only override font-family doesn't mean it will remove the others.

Answer (score 4):

Look into specificity of your css rules.

If in ui-kit you have something like:

```
.parent .child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and in your main.css:

```
.child {
  width: 50%;
}
```

your css will get overriden by ui-kit.

---

**Your css has to be at least as specific as the ui-kit**  to override it.

Comment: And ofc. if you want to override the UI-kit css you need to be at least as specific as them in your selectors. 

Their CSS:
.parent .child

Comment: But If I want to add class in my main.css and she overwrite a property, how can i do this ?

Comment: I've posted my answer down below @PaulWattellier :)

Comment: in your case you could do this: `.gradient li .white {color: white;}`

Comment: It is good practice to avoid using framework classes in your own css. 
Framework classes should be left as they are, and you can always add your own class to an element and modify that in your css.

Comment: @IvanaG.B. Yes that's why I wont write the same class. 
 Ok that's great. many thx. I have only question. What is the difference between .gradient li .white and just .white ? Why first is on success and second is overwrited ?

Comment: Because the .gradient li .white is "deeper" than just .white. When an element has more specific selectors the browser will look at that, as the valid style to use.

It's not good practice to use framework classes or to override styles at all. But it's very very hard not to when not using a precompiler. So I'll actually not call it bad practice. 

If you just keep adding more classes to your elements, that is bad practice as well. Choose the lesser evil.

Comment: @PaulWattellier imagine you see a basket of oranges on the table. you can say "give me an orange" or you can be more specific like "give me that big lumpy orange on the left".  That is ` .white ` vs. ` .gradient li .white `